# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when i open a C# file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS2015 Professional with Update 2 and created a new MVC4 web application. I created a view - no problem, created a new script - no problem. But when i open any C# file, even a new one that i create, my VS `has stopped working` followed by `visual studio is restarting`.. I can even run the project no problem, it seems that only opening C# files causes the project to bug. has anyone else had this problem or know how to fix this?

Comment: I had the same trouble and I got fixed only after full re-installation of VS2015. And this is something related with Update 2.

Comment: yup, this is what i had to do. Thanks